# Правописание частицы "полу" (в слове "полумороз")

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно написать "полумороз"?

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно написать *полумороз*?

Так, как написано у Вас: слитно.

См.  [***"Русский орфографический словарь"***:](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83*&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, слово словарями не фиксируется.
Во-вторых, здесь, да еще в слитном написании, это вряд ли можно частица.

А в остальном - да, написание слитное, все как у Вас. см. ответ slava1947.